# Why does this contract work on Ropsten but not on a private blockchain?

Tags: solidity, evm, ropsten

The following contract runs successfully in Ropsten but not on a private blockchain. I assumed it could be a gas issue. So I increased the gaslimit and started a new blockchain but I get the same issue.

The txn runs but the array called contracts is not updated.

It is not the contract code but the private blockchain. How should I check this to find the error?

Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract RegisterContract {

    uint public contractWeight;
    mapping(bytes32=>string) public contracts;

    function addContract ( string jsonInput, bytes32 hashKey) public {
        contracts[hashKey] = jsonInput;
    }

    function addWeight (uint weight) public {
        contractWeight = weight;
    }
}
```

Txns -

> > > eth.pendingTransactions [{
> > >           blockHash: null,
> > >           blockNumber: null,
> > >           from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
> > >           gas: 4700388,
> > >           gasPrice: 100000000000,
> > >           hash: "0xa441d958c487cf2b80f1ecdeba15c7b17899d9c632a280ba429c394d7835ba06",
> > >           input: "0x4c228d4400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000403966383664303831383834633764363539613266656161306335356164303135613362663466316232623062383232636431356436633135623066303061303800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> > >           nonce: 788,
> > >           r: "0xd9243d6f2c4610a67510083a74f3ed70a1b7a3e576d7da0722c4336b2f40070b",
> > >           s: "0x5f0de0653daf4a74f04eb8854dd46847466e133a01f5ff559c2e629c0ffa2291",
> > >           to: "0xfb63afbe6798270daaa61ba19122c346fb57affb",
> > >           transactionIndex: 0,
> > >           v: "0x2b693",
> > >           value: 0 }]
> > >       eth.pendingTransactions []
> > >       con.contracts("9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08")
> >
> > ""
> >
> > > eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xa441d958c487cf2b80f1ecdeba15c7b17899d9c632a280ba429c394d7835ba06")
> > >       {   blockHash:
> > >       "0x0a62b865d8b6887fa0760779443b0584161ae9320b2073ef403ee13c02516a2b", 
> > >       blockNumber: 263081,   contractAddress: null,   cumulativeGasUsed:
> > >       4700388,   from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
> > >       gasUsed: 4700388,   logs: [],   logsBloom:
> > >       "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> > >       root:
> > >       "0xbf67affe7553839628f283b8436fbba2f1c39b8aff8d270c767cfa8ac4054bde", 
> > >       to: "0xfb63afbe6798270daaa61ba19122c346fb57affb",   transactionHash:
> > >       "0xa441d958c487cf2b80f1ecdeba15c7b17899d9c632a280ba429c394d7835ba06", 
> > >       transactionIndex: 0 }

Comment: Is your private blockchain testrpc (ganache-cli) based?

Comment: No, I just started a geth node in private. It is not testrpc. I think must be some kind of gas issue.

Comment: I've tried your contract with a private blockchain with geth v1.8.3 and solc v0.4.21 and it works as expected. What is your genesis file? Any extra details that helps reproduce the problem will be helpful.

Comment: I finally sorted this out. It was related to bytes32 not being accurate. It was related to 0x. I had no error msg and I had before gas issues so I thought it was a gas issue.